# Drink dispensing machine using Android Things

Tags: android-things

I'm building a liquid dispensing/vending machine. Here are the features it'll have:

- The machine will have a big touchscreen and user can interact with it and select her options. It should also have a capability to show animations/videos.
- It'll have motors to control the flow of different fluids and dispense some liquids. It is controlling around 12-15 sensors, and 12-15 motors/relays, probably a camera.
- Machine also needs to have a payment method integration.
- Also, it should be connected to internet and receive commands from a smartphone app/web and send some sensor information to a common database.

Do you think a Raspberry Pi 3 running Android Things is an appropriate platform for this?  Can all of the features above be implemented that way?

Comment: I think a raspberry pi would be perfect for that - I'm not sure about the Android part, though, but I think it's been done.

Comment: Do you know if I can get some references on how to build it. This would be my first raspberry project.

Comment: Do you know python? If not, learn that first.

Comment: Welcome -- but we're actually *not* a discussion forum, and invitations to brainstorm widely are not appropriate to the format.  Hence, I've edited your post to focus on a few objective questions.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Comment: I have good experience with python and have developed web applications using  django, flask.

Comment: @goldilocks - I apologize if this not an appropriate forum. Do you know of any internet forums where I could get some ideas/recommendations?

The edited version looks better, Thanks!

Comment: The Pi Foundation has a discussion style forum: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: @user2485594 Just do some research with searches like "raspberry pi GPIO tutorial", "raspberry pi touchscreen tutorial", "rpi camera tutorial", etcetera.

Comment: @user2485594 And its completely fine to ask questions here once you get started on your project - just make sure it's a specific question about one or more specific problems/etc, and make sure to do your own research first.